# How to post an online image to Twitter using NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, api, twitter

I am trying to post an online image (eg. https://cdn.pulselive.com/test/client/pl/dev/i/default-thumbnails/t8.png) using NodeJS and Twitter API. I have used [Twit](https://github.com/ttezel/twit) for the development, but I am not sure how to put the media type for the image. Currently, since I havent specified the media type, it is leading to an error that says please specify the type of an image.